# HTML DELETE Method on a single button

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel with a `Route::resource()` controller and to delete something it needs to run the function `destroy()`. This method requires a DELETE HTTP method to go off. How do I do this on a single button?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a form around the delete button. This will not add anything to the page visually.

For example:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'deleteForm']) }}
  <input type="submit" class="deleteBtn" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The Laravel Form helper automatically spoofs the form and adds the hidden field for the `DELETE` method.

Then you can style the button using the `.deleteBtn` class. If the button needs to be positioned inline, you can even assign a `display: inline;` property to the `.deleteForm` class.

Comment: This won't work. `delete` method will not function in form' Rather you need to set 'method=>"post"' and add hidden element `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">` Ref: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: @ArifulHaque Actually, the I've used the Laravel Form helper here. This automatically spoofs the form and adds the hidden field. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form

Comment: Thanks for explain. If you can update the answer with explanation, I can withdraw the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a form and use Laravel's [Form Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing)

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

or you could use ajax *(Example code below uses jQuery)*

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_URL',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this library https://gist.github.com/soufianeEL/3f8483f0f3dc9e3ec5d9 to implement this:

```
<a href="posts/2" data-method="delete" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" data-confirm="Are you sure?">
```